# How to switch two components in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, swap

I was wondering how to switch the components in an array. My goal is to rearrange this array in numerical order, but when I try it keeps throwing up the exception *"Index 22 out of bounds for length 9"*

```java
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < intArray.length - 1; j++)
        if (intArray[j - 1] > intArray[j]) {
            swap(intArray[j - 1], intArray[j], intArray);
        }
    System.out.print(intArray[i]);
    System.out.print(" , ");
}
```

```java
public static void swap(int a, int b, int[] arr) {
    int x = arr[a];
    arr[a] = arr[b];
    arr[b] = x;

}
```

Comment: Youre passing the values (`intArray[j-1], intArray[j]`) to `swap`. You should pass `j - 1` and `j`

Comment: In Java, you can use [`java.util.Collections.swap`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_swap.htm) to swap two items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing in the indices instead of the values of the array

i.e. Changing

```java
if (intArray[j-1] > intArray[j]){
    swap(intArray[j-1], intArray[j], intArray);
}
```

to

```java
if (intArray[j-1] > intArray[j]){
    swap(j-1, j, intArray);
}
```

Also your outermost loop runs 1 less than last element of `intArray`.

You could use

```
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++)
```

instead